# Unable to deploy Dynamic Web Project to Websphere 7 Runtime in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, ant

We have a Dynamic Web Project (not a Maven project). We have an ANT build.xml to generate our EAR package. The web.xml, application.xml was already existing.

While trying to Run this project (from Eclipse - Kepler) to an Websphere 7.0 Runtime, we are getting the following error.

> This version of WebSphere Application Server supports enterprise
>   applications at Java EE 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 and 5.0 specification level.

Our project facet is showing Dynamic Web Project 3.0 and Java 1.6.

We created another fresh, empty 'Dynamic Web Project' and that was getting added to the WAS 7.0 runtime. When checking it's Facets, it was showing Dynamic web project 2.5.

Even after trying to change our project's facet from 3.0 to 2.5, still we are facing the same problem.

When running the ANT goals, the EAR is getting generated without any problem. ***We do not want developers to build an EAR , deploy to WAS server to test even a small code change. We want developers to use the WAS runtime in Eclipse to easily test the code changes as the developers make them*.**

How can we solve this problem ?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but, i guess we created a new project (which was deploying as described in the question post) and manually copied the files from the other project to the new project.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Java version which you are using to build the application in eclipse.

Right click on project --> goto Properties.

Check Java Build path & Java compiler version. (You should be able to change the version to 1.5).

I guess your ant script is ok, you can forcefully set the target compile version in the script if you want to.

Comment: The facet was showing up as Java 1.6 , let me check the jdk version.